# FME 2021 Overwrite one feature in a geopackage

Tags: features, fme-form, geopackage, delete, overwriteoutput

I am using FME 2021 and would like to delete or overwrite one feature in a Geopackage. Is there any tool in FME that will be able to delete or overwrite a feature. For information, When I created the geopackage I did not save the workspace.

Comment: Without knowing FME too well I think that SQLExecutor should work.